# Active MQ - Multiple Broker instance

Tags: activemq-classic, messagebroker, broker

Being a newbie in ActiveMQ, want to know the pros and cons of configuring multiple broker instances in a single ActiveMQ and configuring multiple ActiveMQ instance (installations) each containing one broker instance.

Simplifying the above, which one to use when,
1. Two ActiveMQ installation (i.e. 2 separate AMQ home) with each having one broker running
2. Single AMQ installation with 2 brokers running (configuring activemq.xml)

My application communicates with both the brokers, but does these two configurations have any difference as per failover scenarion or with respect to performance?

Comment: This question is a little bit too broad for SO. For example: Describe the problem you have so far, and how a multi-broker instance approach on top of it causes further problems.

Comment: @Beryllium: I am configuring this to setup production environment. Before making a final decision, want to know pros-cons